# Unit Testing and Code Coverage are showing as 0% in Sonar

Tags: c#, unit-testing, code-coverage, sonarqube

I am trying to set up unit testing and code coverage for a C# project. I am using sonar runner as the analyzer, Gallio 3.4.14 OpenCover4.5.1 
This is the sonar-project.properties file:

```
sonar.projectKey=Foo

sonar.projectName=Foo-SonarQube Runner

sonar.projectVersion=1.0

# Path to the source directories (required)
sonar.sources=.

sonar.language=cs

sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.solution.file=Foo.sln

sonar.silverlight.4.mscorlib.location=C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies
\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v5.0

sonar.dotnet.excludeGeneratedCode=true

sonar.dotnet.4.0.sdk.directory=C:/WIndows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319
sonar.dotnet.version=4.0


sonar.gallio.runner=IsolatedProcess

sonar.gallio.coverage.tool=OpenCover 

sonar.donet.visualstudio.testProjectPattern=**.Tests;   **.UnitTests

sonar.opencover.installDirectory=C:/Program Files (x86)/OpenCover
sonar.dotnet.test.assemblies=FooUnitTests\bin\Release\FooUnitTests.dll
```

It runs successfully but in the logs I see that Gallio didnt execute:

```
No assembly to check with Gendarme

Skipping the non generated assembly of project : Foo

No assembly to check with NDeps

Gallio won't execute as there are no test projects.
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Double-check your test project patterns:
`sonar.donet.visualstudio.testProjectPattern=**.Tests;   **.UnitTests`

Try this instead:
`sonar.donet.visualstudio.testProjectPattern=*Tests;*UnitTests`

Also, toward the top of the sonar-runner output (within the first 20 or so lines), you should see some lines like this:

```
05:40:07.021 INFO  - Initializing Hibernate
05:40:13.601 INFO  - Load project settings
05:40:13.653 INFO  - The following 'sln' file has been found and will be used: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\920b95942ca1a758\Sonar\MyProject-Sonar.sln
05:40:17.276 INFO  - The project 'MyProject.Tests' has been qualified as a test project.
05:40:19.235 INFO  - The project 'MyOther.Project.Tests' has been qualified as a test project.
```

If you're not seeing this, try running sonar-runner with `-X` to enable debugging output. This should give you more details as to what patterns are being used to match test projects.

Additionally, any paths need to use forward slashes (`/`), so the following need to be changed:

```
sonar.silverlight.4.mscorlib.location=C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v5.0
sonar.dotnet.test.assemblies=FooUnitTests\bin\Release\FooUnitTests.dll
```

To this:

```
sonar.silverlight.4.mscorlib.location=C:/Program Files (x86)/Reference Assemblies/Microsoft/Framework/Silverlight/v5.0
sonar.dotnet.test.assemblies=FooUnitTests/bin/Release/FooUnitTests.dll
```

Comment: [22:52:38][Step 3/3] 22:52:38.479 INFO  - The following 'sln' file has been found and will be used: C:TeamCity\Foo\Foo.sln
[22:52:38][Step 3/3] 22:52:38.480 INFO  - The old .NET parameter 'sonar.donet.visualstudio.testProjectPattern' has been found and will be used. Its value: '*.Tests;*.UnitTests'
[22:52:40][Step 3/3] 22:52:40.538 INFO  - Apply project exclusions

Comment: Although it seems that sonar-runner found the sln file, the Gallio doesnt execute. Yes for the testProjectPattern I have one * but when I posted * wasnt appearing. I wonder whether there is a need to create path for coverage and unit testing reports :                    # Path to the integration tests execution report
sonar.gallio.it.reports.path=reports/it-gallio-report.xml
 
# Path to the code coverage report
sonar.gallio.it.coverage.reports.path=reports/it-coverage-report.xml I changed the \ but still it is giving the same results.

Comment: The report paths are only needed if you're using 'reuseReport' mode, which I assume you are not using.  Try removing the dot (.) from your patterns so that it's just '*Tests'. For pattern syntax, see: http://docs.codehaus.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#RunninganAnalysisonaC%23Solution-PathPatterns

Comment: ok so now I get coverage since I can see that coverage has started to pick up I think.                                                           10:51:45.740 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.gallio.CoverageReportSensor@72fdeacb...
10:51:45.756 INFO  - (Safe mode) Parsing Gallio it coverage reports:
10:51:45.756 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.gallio.CoverageReportSensor@72fdeacb done: 16

Comment: And now I have isolate the issue for unit tests                         
10:39:08.557 INFO  - Test assembly not found using pattern FooUnitTests/bin/Release/FooUnitTests.dll, fallback to visual s
tudio default assembly location
10:39:08.557 WARN  - Test assembly not found at the following location: C:\TeamCity\FooU
nitTests\bin\Debug\FooUnitTests.dll
, using the following configuration:
  - csproj file: C:\TeamCity\FooUnitTests\FooUnitTests.csproj

Comment: I added sonar.dotnet.buildConfiguration=Release to point the build config to Release instead of Debug but then I get 11:02:06.525 ERROR - Tried to get a CoverageTool with name OpenCover FooUnitTests.dll, but such a tool is not supported.

Comment: You'll likely need the Debug build to get the coverage details you want.  It would be helpful to know your solution layout.  If you're solution has a project named "FooUnitTests" and you're wanting to use the output of that project, you need to either make the `sonar.dotnet.test.assemblies` path relative to the project file and/or use the solution file pattern, or you need to use the `sonar.donet.visualstudio.testProjectPattern` property.  I would suggest using this:  `sonar.dotnet.test.assemblies=$(SolutionDir)/FooUnitTests/bin/Release/FooUnitTests.dll `

Comment: I solved that problem by adding "Release" at Sonar Settings/General Settings/.Net under Build Configuration. Now I have the coverage working and it is showing how many percent and highlighting the parts of the code that aren't tested BUT there is now another issue.

Comment: Start time: 11:25 PM
Initializing the runtime and loading plugins.
Verifying test files.
Initializing the test runner.
Running the tests.
[error] Assembly FooUnitTests
Cannot run tests because the MSTest executable was not found

Comment: I think I got to insatll a Visual Studio Agent

Comment: if this answer addressed the original issue you posted, please remember to mark it as the answer in Stackoverflow

Comment: Well it solved it and not, MsTest.exec from Gallio is not running the test, so the answer solved partially the problem but not completely.

Comment: [16:31:02][Step 3/3] 16:31:02.433 INFO  - Gallio Echo - Version 3.4 build 11

Comment: [16:31:02][Step 3/3] 16:31:02.435 INFO  - Get the latest version at http://www.gallio.org/
[16:31:02][Step 3/3] 16:31:02.727 INFO  - Initializing the runtime and loading plugins.
[16:31:05][Step 3/3] 16:31:05.166 INFO  - Verifying test files.
[16:31:05][Step 3/3] 16:31:05.429 INFO  - Initializing the test runner.
[16:31:05][Step 3/3] 16:31:05.462 INFO  - Running the tests.

[16:31:14][Step 3/3] 16:31:14.276 INFO  - 
[16:31:14][Step 3/3] FooUnitTests (running for 3m:27s)
[16:31:14][FooUnitTests] Cannot run tests because the MSTest executable was not found

Comment: this is what I get and it looks like Gallio team never addressed this issue